# Segue from NavigationController to View Controller throwing termination of NSException

Tags: ios, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to add a BarButton to the Navigation Items in my view controllers that will segue to a PageViewController. I figured this would be pretty straightforward, but when I tap the button, I receive this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

XCode's editor shows:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

Here is my setup:

**ViewController w/ Navigation Bar Button:**

```
class AudioBookViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationBarDelegate{

@IBAction func helpButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.SegueFromAudiobooksToHelp, sender: self)

    //The exception is thrown when trying to perform the segue above

    Thread.callStackSymbols.forEach{print("    ",$0)}
}
...
```

**Custom Class PageViewController:**

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

let screens = ["Screen1","Screen2"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self as UIPageViewControllerDelegate
    self.dataSource = self as UIPageViewControllerDataSource
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: screens[0])
    setViewControllers([vc!], // Has to be a single item array, unless you're doing double sided stuff I believe
        direction: .forward,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier, let index = screens.index(of: identifier){
        if index > 0{
            return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: screens[index - 1])
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier, let index = screens.index(of: identifier){
        if index < screens.count - 1 {
            return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: screens[index + 1])
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return screens.count
}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    if let identifier = viewControllers?.first?.restorationIdentifier, let index = screens.index(of: identifier){
            return index
    }
    return 0
}
```

}

**My Constants Enum:**

```
struct Constants {

struct NotificationKeys{
    ...

}

struct Segues {
    ....
    static let SegueFromAudiobooksToHelp = "SegueFromAudiobooksToHelp"
    static let SegueFromTopicsToHelp = "SegueFromTopicsToHelp"
    ....
}

struct RegistrationOutcome{
    ...

}
}
```

**And, here is a screenshot of my Storyboard displaying the segue:**

Segue is from AudiobooksViewController to PageViewController, with an IBAction sent from the help button
[image: Segue from Audiobooks VC to Help VC]

**This is my first time running a stack trace...** hopefully I am doing this correctly. I ran the print stack statement right after the segue code.

```
 0   KA Audio Book                       0x00000001000102a8 _TFC13KA_Audio_Book23AudioBookViewController17helpButtonPressedfP_T_ + 260
 1   KA Audio Book                       0x000000010001070c _TToFC13KA_Audio_Book23AudioBookViewController17helpButtonPressedfP_T_ + 72
 2   UIKit                               0x000000019792bd30 <redacted> + 96
 3   UIKit                               0x0000000197a9f880 <redacted> + 168
 4   UIKit                               0x000000019792bd30 <redacted> + 96
 5   UIKit                               0x000000019792bcb0 <redacted> + 80
 6   UIKit                               0x0000000197916128 <redacted> + 452
 7   UIKit                               0x0000000197916290 <redacted> + 812
 8   UIKit                               0x000000019792b59c <redacted> + 584
 9   UIKit                               0x000000019792b0c4 <redacted> + 2484
 10  UIKit                               0x0000000197926328 <redacted> + 2988
 11  UIKit                               0x00000001978f6da0 <redacted> + 340
 12  UIKit                               0x00000001980e075c <redacted> + 2736
 13  UIKit                               0x00000001980da130 <redacted> + 784
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001919eeb5c <redacted> + 24
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001919ee4a4 <redacted> + 524
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001919ec0a4 <redacted> + 804
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019191a2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
 18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001933ce198 GSEventRunModal + 180
 19  UIKit                               0x00000001979617fc <redacted> + 684
 20  UIKit                               0x000000019795c534 UIApplicationMain + 208
 21  KA Audio Book                       0x000000010004f65c main + 76
 22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001908fd5b8 <redacted> + 4
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**Update:**
I've replaced the PageViewController with a regular ViewController and the segue works fine. This confirms that the issue is with the PageViewController that I am segueing into. I believe my 1st screen VC of the PageViewController is not being created or referenced correctly. This is my first time using a PageViewController, so I must be missing something...

Comment: It's hard to diagnose on the basis of what is provided. Can you include everything that appeared in the console? Usually there is more there (which might look cryptic/unimportant at first glance, but there's often information that can be culled from it). In the absence of that, a stack trace can be useful, too. You might also add an exception breakpoint, which sometimes can help identify the precise line of code that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've reached a solution... I was unable to completely programmatically set up my pageview controller. Instead, I had to create a ViewController Storyboard element for each page, while naming each ViewController names that correspond with identifiers within my PageViewController.

Make sure 'Use Storyboard ID is checked'.